# Posting to Facebook page from Facebook application without login to facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication

i am trying to post into a Facebook **Page** using PHP.
I have created a Facebook application, and 
I am able to post into regular accounts **FEED**, using the very helpful code i found out in : [Daily Automatic post in facebook users wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554956/daily-automatic-post-in-facebook-users-wall) .

to summarize it does:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array('appId'  => 'xxxxxxxx',
                               'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',));

$post = array('message'   => 'Message to user');

$post_id = $facebook->api("/$USER_ID/feed", "post", $post);
```

There is no need in any access_token what so ever.
i have granted my application with the following permissions from the PAGE (and from the regular account) : publish_stream,manage_pages

But... this doesn't seem to work with Facebook PAGE.
i do not seem to be able to post to it from my app.
i have tried the following, and other combinations, but Facebook doesn't return any error message, nor doesn't posts:

```
$feed = '/MYPAGEID/feed';

$post_id = $facebook->api($feed, "post", $post);
```

Your help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the documentation for the [Page object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) it says:

> To impersonate the Page when posting to the wall (i.e. post as the
>   Page, and not the current user), you must use a Page access_token with
>   the manage_pages and publish_stream permissions

and

> To perform the following operations as a Page, and not the current
>   user, you must use the Page's access token, not the user access token
>   commonly used for reading Graph API objects. This access token can be
>   retrieved by issuing an HTTP GET to /USER_ID/accounts with the
>   manage_pages permission. This will return a list of Pages (including
>   application profile Pages) to which the user has administrative
>   access, along with access_tokens for those Pages. Alternatively, you
>   can get a page access token for a single, specific, page by issuing an
>   HTTP GET to /PAGE_ID?fields=access_token with the manage_pages
>   permission, as described above. Publishing to a Page also requires the
>   publish_stream permission, unless otherwise noted.

Also, be sure to check the [Authenticating as a Page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/) tutorial.

Comment: Thanks Nitzan, just tried that, but the problem is that when the PAGE user is logged off, this TOKEN is not valid anymore, and i cannot post to it anymore. what i need, is like in 'regular' Facebook account - even if the user is logged off, my app can post to its feed.

Comment: There is no way to have a page access token with out having a logged in user with a valid access token of his own. Working with pages, much like in the facebook interface, is done by users even if the calls are being made from servers.

Comment: Thanks Nitzan, i understand. what bothers me is that i can update **Profile** Facebook account, **without any access_token**, but i cannot update a **Page** Facebook account. i wonder if there is any way around this. why **Page** is different than **Pofile**

Comment: No, that's incorrect, you can not update a facebook user profile using the graph api without an access_token. Can you please share with me how you managed to do that?

Comment: @NitzanTomer, while you correct on most points, your last statement is wrong. There is a way to publish updates to user's feed without his `access_token` by requiring `publish_stream` permission and using application's `access_token`.

Comment: @JuicyScripter, I stand corrected, though I seriously doubt that this is the scenario he's referring to...  My first clue is that he had no mention of "application access token" in his question/comments.

Comment: @eranlevi, no there is no way to post updates to page without `access_token` But you can [Extend](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/) the  user's (who own the page) `access_token` to be able to retrieve page `access_token` from `accounts` connection while user isn't logged in)

Comment: @NitzanTomer - i use the application secret when i instantiate the Facebook class, if this is what u'r referring to. otherwise i d not use any access token.

Comment: @JuicyScripter, thanks for your reply. actually what I need is the ability to update few different Facebook pages, which (may) belong to different users on behalf my application, without logging in. those users might be offline when i try to update their pages. might even want to use cron job. is it possible with the link u have provided?

Comment: The php sdk is probably taking care of getting the access token for you so you're not aware of it, doesn't mean it's not there and that you're not using it. As @JuicyScripter said, you can extend a given (still valid) access token for a user, or if you're using the server-side auth flow then you already get a long lived token (about 2 months), during that time you can use the token (unless it gets invalidated). But when that expires you'll need to user to interact with your app to get a new valid one.

Comment: @NitzanTomer , agreed, i can get 60 days token. but what happens if the user logs explicitly off from Facebook? can i still use this token? from checks i did AFAIK i cannot use this token. will be happy to be stand corrected.

Comment: If the user logs out of facebook it should not invalidate your access token, however there are other cases for invalidation of the access token, some are stated in [Handling Invalid and Expired Access Tokens](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/access-token-expiration/). If/when that happens, you can no longer use the access token, and won't be able to get a new one until the user himself interacts with your application.

Comment: @NitzanTomer, thanks a lot for your comments by far. so, as per your comment, will I be able to persist those 60 days access tokens in some DB, and write a post for several different pages in a row, like when using cron tab (of course if the Page's owner didnt change his pwd, nor 60 days didn't pass, etc.)?

Comment: simple process: 1) get & store the admin extended `access_token` AND email address 2) catch the `access_token` errors (expiry, password changes...etc) 3) send the admin an email to re-generate and store a fresh `access_token`

Comment: @NitzanTomer, yup, i was able to create access_tokens to two pages, and post to both Pages. even after they logged off. Again, thanks a lot for the answers, **Toda :)**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to post to your page be sure to get the right acces token from your admin account.
Go to the oath page off facebook generate the right token. Go to get access token and then select to options you want.

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, just tried that, but the problem is that when the PAGE user is logged off, this TOKEN is not valid anymore, and i cannot post to it. what i need, is like in 'regular' Facebook account - even if the user is logged off, my app can post to its feed.

Comment: thanks a lot, i found my answer - see comments for the other answer